# STOP certain animation when two layers collide JQUERY

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, collision-detection, game-engine, layer

First of all sorry for my terrible English, isn´t my native language.

I´m trying to do a little RPG game with a character walking across a map (old rpg style, like zelda or pokemon maybe).

You can see my code here: [jsFiddle URL](http://jsfiddle.net/Osaka_lime/jV9Ls/22/)

i´m a bit stuck, cause when my two layers collide, I can´t find a way to stop my .animate in the direction of the other layer, but allow it to move in other directions. For example:

If #character goes to the right and collide with the other layer(#stone01, the black one), i want to stop moving to the the right but allow to move up, down and left.

Here you can see my Javascript code to detect my two elements collide:

```
function collision($yo, $obstaculo) {
    var x1 = $yo.offset().left;
    var y1 = $yo.offset().top;
    var h1 = $yo.outerHeight(true);
    var w1 = $yo.outerWidth(true);
    var b1 = y1 + h1;
    var r1 = x1 + w1;
    var x2 = $obstaculo.offset().left;
    var y2 = $obstaculo.offset().top;
    var h2 = $obstaculo.outerHeight(true);
    var w2 = $obstaculo.outerWidth(true);
    var b2 = y2 + h2;
    var r2 = x2 + w2;

    if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Hope anyone can give me any tip about it, THANKS!

Comment: Firstly separate your game objects from the visual display of those elements. You work out your collisions so that they affect the velocity of the game objects. The display is purely a representation of the game state. Using animate is just a means of smoothing animation between positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is get the position of the #stone and the position of the character and check to see when they are the same if they are the same I would return false and set a flag canMoveRight to false.

I assume that a keydown event handler would be used and the distance would be 1px and first I check if the layers overlap and proceed accordingly

```
var canMoveRight = true;

$("#character")
    .on(
    {
        keydown : function()
        {
            if(checkLayerOverlap())
                $("#character").stop();
            else
                move(1);

            return false;
        }
    }
);

function move(distance)
{
    $("#character").animate({
        right : "+=" + distance + "px"
    },"slow");
}

function checkLayerOverlap()
{
    var isOverLapping = false;
    var characterPosition = $("#character").position();
    var stonePosition = $("#stone").position();

    if(characterPosition.right == stonePosition.right)
    {
        canMoveRight = false;
        isOverLapping = true;
    }

    return isOverLapping;
}
```

of course all that logic should be expressed in objects so your $("#character") would be

```
var Character = {
 canMoveRight = true,
 move : function(distance)
 {
    //code here
 }
```

}

this is just a hint :)

Comment: Ok, i have found a solution based on your idea, thank you very much!

My problem right now, it´s that I want to use my function collision( ) to various elements with the same class name. I really dont know how to do that, I have tried to do it with .each storing all the distance and width from all divs in a single var, but i dont know how to display ir (maybe with some kind of FOR loop?). Thanks Again!

Comment: @user3214649 If this answered your question then give it a checkmark. This will 'close' this question and it will return the favor to alex by giving him points for answering your question.

Comment: Thanx for the tip, I´m also new using Stackoverflow ^^